# Swift constraint error when adding UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add a custom navigation bar to my app, but whenever it loads I get the 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' error.  I can't seem to programatically remove any of the constraints - and I definitely haven't added any.

Console Output:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000092750 UILabel:0x7ffc40507d20'Configure'.firstBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x6000007b18e0'TitleView(0x7ffc40503120)'.top + 23   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000092840 UILabel:0x7ffc40507d20'Configure'.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x6000007b18e0'TitleView(0x7ffc40503120)'.top   (active)>"
```

App Delegate:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let nav1 = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: CustomNavBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
let mainView = TableViewController()
nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

CustomNavBar Class:

```
self.frame.size.height = 60
self.backgroundColor = appColour
self.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 30)!
]
self.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-5, for: .default)
```

ViewController:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(start))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -7, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Folder")!, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(viewSaved))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -7, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
self.title = "Configure"
```

I just can't figure out what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For any of your elements, did you set `translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints` to `false`?

Comment: Can you just try removing this line `nav1.navigationItem.titleView?.firstBaselineAnchor = nil` and see if it works...

Comment: Sorry I haven't set the autoresizingmask, also that was me just testing it sorry - will remove the line now.  It doesnt work without that line as well.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is with your font-size in your CustomNavBar Class, reduce the font size until you don't get the constraint error.

```
self.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: <30>)!
]
```